# Well isolated DB storage for each user

Tags: database, security, cloud, data-protection

I have financial pet project which I'm considering make public. The data is stored in MySQL database. While I'm only the one user and it's installed locally there are no security issues. However making the project public means to share the database between multiple users. Thus there is a risk to compromise a private financial data. So, I'm looking for the way to solve this problem.

I see the following possible options of solving this:

1. Only local usage. Each user downloads sources, setup environment, installs the application locally.
2. Installing the application online and protecting access to the data of other users programatically on back-end level.
3. Duplicating the database on the server for each user.
4. Use some cloud-base solution and have separate DB instance for each user. (I have no experiance with cloud ecosystem)

Each option has own downsides and I'm not sure about any. I need some good option which will not be expensive, will be easy to use by users and provide relliable data protection.